# tengo un programa que lee contraseñas, funciona bien pero aun cuando se lee la contraseña exitosamente, me pide otra contraseña

Tags: java, array, matrices, matriz, vectores

como pueden ver, aqui tengo un programa bastante adelantado, el cual consiste en una contraseña que debe ser de al menos 10 caracteres y no más de 16 caracteres, puede contener únicamente los caracteres: ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’, ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’,’4’, ‘5’,ademas, No se pueden generar series de letras o de números de dos o más caracteres ya sea en orden ascendente o descendente. Ejemplos: “ab13a2b1ad” “a1b23ca35ac1b” “ac321ac251a2”. No pueden presentarse caracteres repetidos uno al lado del otro. Ejemplos: “aa2bc1b2c5a2b” a1c33d13adb142”. Después de cada letra puede aparecer cualquier número, Después de cada número puede aparecer cualquier letra, El diseño debe involucrar al menos un arreglo unidimensional(vector) y un arreglo bidimensional (matriz) para evaluar si una contraseña es Válida siempre y cuando cumpla con TODOS los requisitos expuestos. Si alguno no se cumple, la contraseña debe ser calificada como No válida. El problema es que cuando pongo los caracteres de la contraseña tal y como me lo pide, deberia finalizar el programa, pero en cambio, me muestra de nuevo la opción de volver a ingresar la contraseña.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pos, ei, esw, ej;
        String Sopciones, Scadena;
        char csel, ccad, dd, ek;
        char Matriz[][] = new char[20][20];
        char Matriz1[][] = new char[20][20];
        char VeContraseña[] = new char[20];
        esw=0;
        do { Sopciones = "elija una opcion \n1. Evaluar contraseña\n2.salir";
            csel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Sopciones).charAt(0);
            switch (csel) {
                case '1':
                    Scadena = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la contraseña ");
                    pos = Scadena.length();
                    if ((pos >= 10) && (pos <= 16)) {
                        LlenarVector(pos, VeContraseña, Scadena);
                        Letras(Matriz);
                        Numeros(Matriz1);
                        for (ei = 0; ei <= pos - 1; ei++) {
                            if ((VeContraseña[ei] != 'a') && (VeContraseña[ei] != 'b') && (VeContraseña[ei] != 'c') && (VeContraseña[ei] != 'd') && 
                                    (VeContraseña[ei] != '1') && (VeContraseña[ei] != '2') && (VeContraseña[ei] != '3') && (VeContraseña[ei] != '4') && (VeContraseña[ei] != '5')) {
                                esw = 2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (esw == 0) {
                            for (ei = 0; ei <= pos - 2; ei++) {
                                for (ej = 0; ej <= 2; ej++) {
                                    ccad = Scadena.charAt(ei);
                                    dd = Scadena.charAt(ei + 1);
                                    if ((ccad == Matriz[0][ej]) && (dd == Matriz[0][ej + 1])) {
                                        esw = 3;
                                    }
                                    if (dd == Matriz[1][ej]) {
                                        esw = 4;
                                    }
                                    if ((ccad == Matriz[0][ej]) && (Matriz[0][ej] == Matriz[1][ej])) {
                                        esw = 5;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            for (ei = 0; ei <= pos - 2; ei++) {
                                for (ek = 0; ek <= 3; ek++) {
                                    ccad = Scadena.charAt(ei);
                                    dd = Scadena.charAt(ei + 1);
                                    if ((ccad == Matriz1[0][ek]) && (dd == Matriz1[0][ek + 1])) {
                                        esw = 3;
                                    }
                                    if (dd == Matriz1[1][ek]) {
                                        esw = 4;
                                    }
                                    if ((ccad == Matriz1[0][ek]) && (Matriz1[0][ek] == Matriz1[1][ek])) {
                                        esw = 5;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        esw = 1;
                        if (esw == 1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "contraseña invalida",
                                    "cantidad de Caracteres invalidos ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                    if (esw== 2) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "contraseña invalida",
                                "Caracteres invalidos ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    if (esw== 3) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "contraseña invalida",
                                "Caracteres ascendentes", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    if (esw== 4) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "contraseña invalida",
                                "Caracteres descendentes", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    if (esw== 5) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "contraseña invalida",
                                "Caracteres se repiten", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    if (esw== 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "contraseña invalida",
                                "MSJ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    esw = 0;

                    break;

                case '2':
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            null, "FIN DEL PROCESO",
                            "msj", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;

                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            null, "opcion invalida ",
                            "msj", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } 

        } while (csel
                != '2');
        
    }

    public static void LlenarVector(int lon, char Vec[], String contra) {
        int ei;
        String Contenedor;
        Contenedor = contra;
        for (ei = 0; ei <= lon - 1; ei++) {
            Vec[ei] = Contenedor.charAt(ei);

        }

    }

    public static void Letras(char Matriz[][]) {
        int ei;
        char Ccom;
        String cad = "abcd";
        for (ei = 0; ei <= 3; ei++) {
            Ccom = cad.charAt(ei);
            Matriz[0][ei] = Ccom;
            Matriz[1][ei] = Ccom;

        }
    }

    public static void Numeros(char Matriz1[][]) {
        int ei;
        char Ccom;
        String cad = "12345";
        for (ei = 0; ei <= 4; ei++) {
            Ccom = cad.charAt(ei);
            Matriz1[0][ei] = Ccom;
            Matriz1[1][ei] = Ccom;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: si esw=0 la contraseña debe ser valida?,o donde estas evaluando si la contraseña ingresada es correcta?

Answer (score 0):

¿en que momento le cambias el valor a la variable **csel** la cual controla el do-while?. Si su valor no cambia el do-while se repite infinitamente.